The word for text appearing word by word
What's the word to describe the fact that some text starts appearing gradually word by word e.g. in the response given by ChatGPT?

I think "word by word" or "word-by-word" is the usual term. Do you want noun, verb, adjective, adverb?

Welcome to ELU. I've corrected the tag for this question. Please take a moment to review the tag help and [edit] your question accordingly: the community needs as much information as possible to help get a word which is just right.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I found this: 'appear dynamically with a typerwriter effect'. What do you think?

That's not a single word.

In machine learning research, this is described as "streaming" the output. See, for instance, this documentation: Text-generation-inference documentation: Streaming.
